# mySQL join table if table 1 column value LIKE table 2 column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table 1

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| name  |  age   | gender |
+-------+--------+--------+
| mark  |  20    |  male  |
| john  |  22    |  male  |
| jenny |  21    | female |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

Table 2

```
+-------+----------+---------+
| name2 |  status  | address |
+-------+----------+---------+
| john  |  single  |  miami  |
| mark  |  single  | new york|
| jenny |  single  |  jersy  |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

I would like to display like this...
for Mark example:
Name:  Mark
Age: 20
Gender: Male
Status: single
address: newyork
PLEASE USE "LIKE" not equal

Comment: why do you need to use `LIKE` instead of `=`?

Comment: This is going to be _horrible_ on large tables, if you need `LIKE` for it's actual purpose

Comment: Did you try anything yourself on your homework?

Comment: -1 No indication of what (if anything) has been tried yourself, or what it is you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `=` is much preferred to use over `LIKE` because `LIKE` is used for pattern matching.

```
SELECT  a.name, a.age, a.gender,
        b.status, b.address
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.name = b.name2
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

if you really want to use `LIKE`,

```
SELECT  a.name, a.age, a.gender,
        b.status, b.address
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.name LIKE b.name2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94919/2)